# JPEG/JPG and TIFF/TIF which is the Correct or Commonly used extension

Tags: image, save

I have found many image editors offering to save the image in JPEG or TIF Format  with Extensions .JPEG/.JPG and .TIF/.TIFF As im developing a image editing tool which format should my app support.

Comment: Are you asking about the format (JPEG or TIFF) to support, or about the extension (.jpeg or .jpg, .tif or .tiff) to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as per comments) you are asking about which extension to prefer for each format, there is very little difference:

**.jpeg**  is (very slightly) more correct-nice-modern

**.jpg**  is (very slightly) more compatible-safe

The compatibility/safety issue refers mainly to old DOS-based filesystems that used the [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) structure. But that is rarely a issue in 2012.

Both are ok - but, please, dont' use uppercase.

The same goes for **.tif** vs **.tiff** (as, BTW, **.html** vs **.htm**)

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is far more common than TIF. PNG is also pretty common now.